# Is there a faster way to uniformly format first- and surnames on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there some 'standard' way of dealing with non-uniformly entered names in pandas dataframes? For example we might have a dataframe about participants to some event. In this dataframe there is a column 'Name' where the name of the participant is listed. 
The names are in different formats (order of first- and surname and capitalization:

1. Firstname Surname
2. firstname Surname
3. Firstname surname
4. Surname, Firstname
5. Surname Firstname
6. surname, Firstname

... and so on.

What is the smartest way to format all names uniformly as 'Firstname Surname'? One could loop through all the rows and use regex but there must be a better way.

Comment: Unless there is a dict or something distinguishing a surname from firstname it will be difficult.

Comment: Row `5`: `Surname Firstname` cannot, in general, be distinguished from Row `1`: `Firstname Surname`.

Comment: I suspected that row5 would not be possible. But in my real dataset If surname comes first there is always a comma after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all names without commas have the first name appear first and those with commas have the last name appear first, you could accomplish this in 2 stages:

First you need to take care of rows with commas - remove the comma and reverse the order of the names:

```
mask = df["Name"].str.contains(",")  # These are the rows we want to change
df.loc[mask, "Name"] = df.loc[mask, "Name"].str.split(", ").apply(reversed).str.join(" ")
```

Then you can use [str.title](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) to enforce case:

```
df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.title()
```